# Configure CD via OpenVpn

Tags: azure-devops

We have private VMs and due to security issue unable to establish direct connection from cloud azure agent to VM. According to the corporate security politics it is possible to establish connection via OpenVpn.
Does anyone faced with such issue? How did you overcome it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

If the target VM, which is behind the firewall and can be access only through VPN connection. And you want to use host agent to target these VMs. This is not available. How do you plan to connect that host agent if it can not send requests to it from your VM? Host Agent is controlled by Microsoft and randomly assign. We could not establish VPN on any host Agent directly.

---

> **You cannot use private connections** such as ExpressRoute or **VPN to
>   connect Microsoft-hosted agents to your corporate network**. The traffic
>   between Microsoft-hosted agents and your servers will be over public
>   network.

Kindly check the networking part of our official doc -- [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking)

Comment: I want to use Hosted Agent to deploy directly to on-prem VM (without build-agents in on-prem area). It seems that there must be some kind of OpenVPN client in the release pipeline to etablish connection and deploy package to on-prem. server.

Comment: @shaddow No need, you just need to make sure your target agent it has an external connectivity , public internet connection. It's able to directly access Azure DevOps Service, that's enough. You could go through part 2 in my above answer. Also take a look at this similar question:  [How to deploy software builds from Azure DevOps to internal servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496908/how-to-deploy-software-builds-from-azure-devops-to-internal-servers)

Comment: We unable to create Private agent on-prem.infrastructure due to security policy. I need to build app. in Azure Hosted Agent and deploy it from it to on-prem server. But deployment possible via OpenVPN only.

Comment: @shaddow Sorry for the misunderstanding. In other words, the target VM, which is behind the firewall and can be access only through vpn connection. And you want to use host agent to target these VMs.  **This is not available.** How do you plan to connect that host agent if it can not send requests to it from your VM? Host Agent is controlled by Microsoft and  randomly assign. We could not establish VPN on any host Agent directly.

Comment: The only workaround here, if you are not allowed to create private agent on the VM directly. You could also choose install agents on any machine which could directly access your VM. If this is also not allowed. Afraid there is no way to handle this so far. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Ok, but what's about something like install OpenVPN client during the build (as CLI tool), add profile file from variables, establish connection make deploy and then disconnect?

Comment: @shaddow  Sorry for later reply. This is not allow and declared clearly.   `You cannot use private connections such as ExpressRoute or VPN to connect Microsoft-hosted agents to your corporate network. The traffic between Microsoft-hosted agents and your servers will be over public network.` You could find this in **our official doc of the networking part** here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking